# Dynamically Positioning Text Below a Horizontal Line in a ggplot with Log10-scaled y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting data in ggplot2 and have set a log10 scale for the y-axis with predefined limits, say `y_max` (e.g., 100) and `y_min` (e.g., 1). I've also added a horizontal line at a given `y_intercept` value. I'd like to add a text annotation (e.g., "hello") just below this horizontal line. However, the y-axis limits and the `y_intercept` values may vary between plots.

The challenge is to position this text at a consistent visual distance below the horizontal line across different plots, regardless of changes to the y-axis limits or `y_intercept` value. How can this be achieved?

Comment: A quick fix would be to set the labels' y-aesthetic to a fraction of the y-value. As you indicated, different y-limits would still affect the spacing between line and label. Would a two-step approach (setting the y-range outside the plot statements) do as well?

Comment: @I_O That quick fix is indeed not what I am looking for. It is critical to keep the visual spacing between line and label consistent across the plots. A two step (or any step) approach would be fine!

Comment: see answer which uses a helper function, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this:

- three example plots with different y-range:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    
    p1 <- 
      data.frame(x = 1, y = c(5, 50, 500), label = rep('hello', 3)) |>
      ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = y)) +
      scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 1e3))
    
    p2 <- p1 + scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 1e4))
    p3 <- p1 + scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 1e5))
```

- create helper function which accepts a `ggplot` object and a vertical offset, queries the plot's y-range (in log10 units) and adds the vertical offset:

```
add_hlabels  <- function(p = last_plot(), v_offset = 0){
  fac  <- 10^(v_offset * dist(layer_scales(p)$y$get_limits()))
  p + geom_text(aes(y = y * fac, label = label))
}
```

- inspect:

```
library(patchwork) ## for convenient plot arrangement

v_offset = -.1

add_hlabels(p1, v_offset) +
  add_hlabels(p2, v_offset) + 
  add_hlabels(p3, v_offset)
```

[image: constant label offset despite varying axis range]

**Edit**
{[ggpp](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpp/)} offers [advanced nudging](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpp/articles/nudge-examples.html#position-functions-and-nudging)